# Button is not showing in output screen when i set under RelativeLayout in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I have mostly used Linearlayout, so it's hard to design in Relativelayout, I just Drag and drop the button in Relativelayout, and when I run this app output appears just blank. The button appears on the preview screen but not on the mobile screen.

**java file:**

package com.example.insagramprofilecreater;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_below="@id/main"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Remove these line android:layout_below="@id/main" from button.

Comment: it's better to learn how it works alongwith drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

remove unwanted `alignParent` properties from button like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your code, `alignParent` Button leads to match to parent `RelativeLayout`. Also do some research on how to use RelativeLayout like [here](https://inducesmile.com/android-tutorials-for-nigerian-developer/understanding-relative-layout-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:layout_below="@id/main"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Remove  `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` if you want your button at bottom or `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` if you want button at top.

You can check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout) for info.

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Button"

      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

try it